# How to disable Bluetooth Pairing Request Pop up in iOS device

Tags: ios, swift, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

While fetching the values from the Bluetooth device(BP Monitor), iOS triggers the "Bluetooth Pairing Request" pop up. How can I disable this request?

Comment: If the peripheral implements encryption for an attribute then pairing is required. Unless you can change the peripheral firmware to not use encryption, the pairing dialog cannot be avoided

Comment: Hi @Paulw11...The device which i am using doesn't required pairing. Also i am not using encryption for the peripheral implementation.

Comment: If the Bluetooth paring pop up is appearing then the characteristic you are interacting with requires encryption. There is nothing you can do on the central side to control this process.